# plot min and max temperature by months

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm very new to using R. I want to create a stacked bar chart displaying the proportion of temperature readings <38C or >=38C as a function of time.

```r
Date    Temperature (C) 
10/22/18 8:00   36.8
10/22/18 12:00  36.8
10/22/18 16:00  36.8
10/23/18 12:00  36.8
10/30/18 16:00  36.8
10/22/18 0:00   36.9
10/29/18 20:00  36.9
10/31/18 8:00   36.9
10/18/18 4:00   37
10/20/18 20:00  37
10/21/18 20:00  37
10/30/18 4:00   37
6/15/18 20:00   36.7
6/16/18 4:00    37
6/16/18 8:00    37.1
6/16/18 12:00   37.1
6/16/18 16:00   37.1
6/16/18 0:00    37.4
4/27/18 20:00   36.4
4/28/18 0:00    36.5
4/28/18 4:00    36.5
4/27/18 18:00   36.7
4/28/18 8:00    36.8
7/31/18 0:00    36.6
8/1/18 4:00     36.6
7/31/18 8:00    36.8
7/31/18 12:00   36.8
7/31/18 16:00   36.8
8/1/18 8:00     36.8
7/30/18 20:00   36.9
7/31/18 4:00    36.9
```

I've tried a variety of different codes, but they don't seem to work well. This is the most recent one I've tried.

```
ggplot(master, aes(event, mastertemps)) + 
 geom_line() + 
 ylim(c(0, 1)) + 
 xlab("") + 
 ylab("Temperature") + 
 scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b %y") + 
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
 ggtitle("2018 Temperatures")
```

This is the error message I received when I ran this

> "Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only"

I want a plot that looks similar to this:

[image: max and min temperature per month]

Comment: Welcome to stack. Please, don't post pictures of your data, but give the data for real using for example `dput` or making an example dataset. See [mcve]

Comment: The error message hints that `event` is not the correct data type. You use a transformation for "date"-types but the variable seems to have another type like string or numeric. As @denis said, if you give sample data we can help better.

Comment: I edited the post to reformat the data example. Thank you for pointing that out @denis

Comment: smop94, there is a difference between what an object looks like on the console and how it is stored. For instance, if you run `class(x$Date)` on your console, according to what we see here, I'm going to bet a lot that you'll see either `"character"` or `"factor"` (but certainly not `"Date"`, which is what `ggplot2` needs it to be).

Comment: Try converting it with something similar to `as.POSIXct("10/22/18 8:00", format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`.

Comment: If this does not work for you, please replace your sample data with the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is your data or a *sample* of it if there is a lot of it. (We don't need much, just enough to reproduce the error and potentially plot enough of your data to get the point across.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crack at plotting daily min-max based on the sample data you have provided:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.csv("test.csv") # stored your sample data as a csv

dat <- dat %>% mutate(date = as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")) # new variable in Date class

d2 <- dat %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(min = min(Temperature), max = max(Temperature)) # new variables with min and max daily temperature

d2 <- d2 %>% gather(var, val, -date) # change the data to long format


ggplot(d2, aes(date, val, colour=var)) + geom_line() + geom_point() # plot
```

[image]

To plot the daily in monthly min-max format:

```
d3 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")) %>% 
  mutate(month = format(date, "%m")) 

d3 <- d3 %>% group_by(month) %>%  summarise(min = min(Temperature), max = max(Temperature))

d3 <- d3 %>% gather(var, val, -month)

d3$month <- as.numeric(d3$month)

ggplot(d3,aes(month, val, colour=var)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks=seq(4, 10, 2), labels=c("Apr", "Jun", "Aug", "Oct")) +
  ylab("Temperature")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for working this out! When I ran this line of code ```d2 <- d2 %>% gather(var, val, -date)```
Error: `NULL` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(x) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors .   That was the error message I recieved

Comment: Check your data to ensure that your mm/dd/yy HH:MM is in character format and not in factor format.